# Worldview-2 imagery coverage

Tags: imagery, worldview-2

I am attempting to acquire imagery from the Worldview-2 satellite, and finding limited coverage for many areas within the United States. Sometimes, coverage is temporally deep for a time period (say 15 June 2018 - 31 October 2018) in limited areas, but no coverage for other areas.

Is this a common occurrence?

I am wondering if I am doing something wrong when trying to download the data.

Comment: What is your data source? Have you tried contacting DigitalGlobe/Maxar to verify the data that is available for your site?

Comment: I haven't contacted them, but I have contacted people that also work with them. I was just wanting to get a sense from the user community as to how much coverage to expect.